# Nginx set_cookie_flag security hardening alternative for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, security, nginx, cookies

By setting `HttpOnly` flag within the relevant Set-cookie directive, it makes certain client-side attacks such as cross-site scripting harder to exploit by preventing trivial capturing of a cookie's value.

Also, by setting `secure` flag within the relevant Set-cookie directive, it prevents a cookie from being intercepted by a man in the middle attack by making sure cookies are never transmitted over unencrypted communications.

I understand that these could be achieved by using the `nginx_cookie_flag_module` and adding `set_cookie_flag HttpOnly secure;` in my nginx configuration.

However according to this [nginx product page](https://www.nginx.com/products/nginx/modules/cookie-flag/):

> **Cookie-Flag**
>
> Set the flags “HttpOnly”, “secure” and “SameSite” for cookies in the “Set-Cookie” upstream response headers.
>
> Support details: Supported by NGINX, Inc. **for active NGINX Plus subscribers**.

So besides subscring to NGINX Plus to get this feature, are there alternative methods to set the HttpOnly and secure flag?

*Background - I am running Wordpress 4.9.6 with PHP-FPM-FCGI 7.1.19 behind NGINX 1.10.3 reverse proxy.*

**TL; DR**

**How do I set HttpOnly and secure flag on Set-Cookie reponse header of Wordpress without a NGINX Plus subscription?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that this can be done upstream directly from Wordpress.

Add the following lines to the top of wp-config.php:

```
@ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', true);
@ini_set('session.cookie_secure', true);
@ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', true);
```

Then restart Wordpress.